# Faltan filas en pygwalker

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Tengo un DataFrame de Pandas, cargado desde un CSV, así:

```
train_df = pd.read_csv("data/train.csv")
```

Luego lo visualizo con PygWalker, así:

```
gwalker = pw.walk(train_df)
```

El problema es que el DF tiene 8600 filas de datos, pero en la pestaña data de la gráfica de PygWalker sólo se muestran 501 filas, paginadas de 100 en 100. Es decir, está ignorando 8100 filas de datos. Por qué?